# How to call and update a Listview of the current Activity after calling a REST service?

Tags: android, rest, listview, service

I have a custom listview where each item contains an "Approve" (green) and "Reject" (red) button. When the user clicks on one of the green buttons, the application should call a webservice Rest, responsible for updating the database, ie, "approving" the clicked listview item, and "rejecting" the others listview items. When the user clicks in one of the "reject" buttons, the service will update only the clicked item in db, "rejecting" this item. The service accessed via URL works correctly.

[image: app mockup]

All services I have used in the other screens so far returning the information in a new activity, but this service must update **in the same activity**, removing all items or only one item. If  remove all items, the app must return to the previous activity (because listview is empty). If remove only one item, the app stays in the same activity.

My question is: how to call a rest service (URL) to update a current activity (without going to another activity), and how to remove listView items after that?

Thank you in advance and sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

You need to add/remove items from your data model, and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.  That lets the ListView know to update itself.